# SilverStripe 3: Select single Image UploadField

Tags: image, silverstripe

I have an image field in dataobject with has_one relation. I have set

`$imageField->setConfig('allowedMaxFileNumber', 1);`

Problem is that I am able to select multiple field. However only one is saving when click on Save
button.

Due to multiple image selection throgh "From Computer" or "From Files", User has an impression, that he can upload multiple files. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r8d0.png

How can I disable multiple image selection for UploadField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a known bug: http://open.silverstripe.org/ticket/8145.
For now, I would suggest that you use the setDescription() method to advise your users that only one file is allowed to be selected.